# C Find all instances of a word

Tags: c, string, char, append

So I'm trying to find all instances of a word using this section of code

```
fseek(src, 0, SEEK_END);
int size = ftell(src); 
fseek(src, 0, SEEK_SET);
int line = 0;
int i = 0;
char ch = ' ';
char *word;
char lastch = 'x';
int j = 0;
int lines[getLines(src)];

for(i = 0; i < getLines(src); i++){
    lines[i] = -1;
}

for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
    ch = fgetc(src);
    printf("%s %c", word, '\n');
    if(!isspace(lastch) && isspace(ch)){

        if(strcmp(word, find) == 0){
            if(lines[j - 1] != line){
                lines[j] = line;
                j++;
            }
        }
    }else{

        if(isspace(lastch) && isspace(ch)){
            continue;
        }else if(isspace(lastch) && !isspace(ch)){
            word = "";
            append(word, ch);
        }else if(!isspace(lastch) && !isspace(ch)){
            append(word, ch);
        }
    }
    lastch = ch;
}
```

Where as append() is

```
char *append(const char *s, char c) {
int len = strlen(s);
char buf[len+2];
strcpy(buf, s);
buf[len] = c;
buf[len + 1] = 0;
return strdup(buf);
}
```

Could anyone explain to me why the String word does not get any characters added into it?

I'm pretty sure it has to do with the append function, thanks.

Comment: So, your question is not about "finding all instances of a word", but why your function `append()` does not work, right?

Comment: You should really read a C tutorial! (And develop some common sense.) After we all told you cca. 5 minutes before that you can't modify a constant string in-place, you're expecting the functions given the answers to your previous question to do that. You haven't even made the effort to understand how the function you're using works. It **doesn't modify the string itself,** instead it **returns a copy of the string the specified character appended to it.**

Comment: Obviously, if you're trying to find all instances of a word, your problem is that you're not crawling the Internet.

Comment: Sorry guys I'm taking an exam, just realized that I just have to do word = append(word, ch); My bad. I'm kind of in a rush, don't really have time. I understand programming, and C, it's just difficult to keep my mind straight when I have 20 minutes left.

Answer (score 0):

So *after having read my comment,* read my answer as well:

```
word = "";
append(word, ch);
```

doesn't do what you think it does. It does not append a character to `word` itself, instead it appends a character to a writable copy of `word`. You should really write

```
} else if(isspace(lastch) && !isspace(ch)) {
    word = append("", ch);
} else if(!isspace(lastch) && !isspace(ch)) {
    char *tmp = append(word, ch);
    free(word);
    word = tmp;
}
```

instead. Also, please use whitespaces and indentation properly, it's hard to read your code.